# Do IPtables for Ubuntu have a wildcard for an IP address

Tags: iptables, wildcard

I am needing to set up IPtables to accept traffic on many internal IP's. Is there a wildcard I can use for part of the ip address?  For example: 192.168.*.*

Or would there a better alternative?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about basic unix/linux knowledge and would be better off at http://unix.stackexchange.com.

Answer (score 10):

iptables does not know wildcards but used the CIDR method. 
F.e: -s 192.168.0.0/24 will cover all the hosts from 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.254.

You can find more info about CIDR [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classless_Inter-Domain_Routing)

Answer (score 8):

No wildcard per se, but you can specify a CIDR netmask:

```
192.168.0.0/16
```

The above would be the CIDR equivalent of the example you gave.

Answer (score 6):

Not really a wildcard, you can match IP Adresses by subnets:

192.168.0.0/16 
192.168.1.0/24
192.168.2.0/25

Another way is to use ipranges like this:
iptables -A INPUT --destination-port 80 -m iprange --src-range From_IP-To_IP -j ACCEPT

There is a second module for --dest-range as well.

Answer (score 3):

`iptables` supports using CIDR notation, so for your example you can use `192.168.0.0/16`.

Unrelatedly, please consider working on your accept-rate.

Answer (score 3):

For future googlers, as of current version of iptables 1.4.7

**Single port IP Range**

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8080 -m iprange --src-range 192.168.0.0-192.168.254.254 -j ACCEPT
```

**Multiple port IP Range**

```
iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m multiport --dports 21,8080 -m iprange --src-range 192.168.0.0-192.168.254.254 -j ACCEPT
```